# My app works fine when it installs from Android Studio but crashes when share it to any other device?

Tags: java, android, xml

My app works fine when it installs from Android Studio, but crashes when sharing it to any other device? Anyone, please help me.

Comment: disable instant Run then make build

Comment: yup. its works fine. thanku

Answer (score 2):

Find the steps to disable **Instant Run**

To disable Instant Run:

```
 1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
 2. Navigate to Build, Execution,Deployment > Instant Run.
 3. Uncheck the boxes > Apply > Ok.
```

Answer (score 1):

1.open the setting form file.
2.redirect to build,execution,Deployment.
3.uncheck instant run.
4.apply then ok.